# Showing ads on every view automatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm implementing Mobclix in my app, and when following the instructions, it tells us to properly release and dealloc the adview. It also tells us that when the view appears, you should call refreshAds and when it disappears you should pause refresh ads:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.adView resumeAdAutoRefresh];
 }
    ￼
    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     [self.adView pauseAdAutoRefresh];
    }
@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidUnload {
[self.adView cancelAd];
self.adView.delegate = nil; 
self.adView = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc {
[self.adView cancelAd];
self.adView.delegate = nil; 
self.adView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

My question is that I have a lot of view controllers, so it would be inconvenient to implement these things on each view. Is there anyway I can call these methods in one place and have it work for all views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is subclass `UIViewController` and have all your `viewController`s to inherit these things.

So basically you could have `AdsViewController.h` wich will look like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h?

@interface AdsViewController: UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) <#AdsViewType#> *adsView;

@end
```

and your `AdsViewController.m` will have to look pretty much like this

```
#import "AdsViewController.h"

@implementation AdsViewController

@synthesize adsView = _adsView;  

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _adsView = [[<#AdsViewType#> alloc] init];
        _adsView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self.adView cancelAd];
    self.adView = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.adView cancelAd];
    self.adsView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.adView resumeAdAutoRefresh];
}
￼
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.adView pauseAdAutoRefresh];
}

@end
```

After this have all your `viewController`s to subclass this instead of `UIViewController`. Hope this helps.